# Present View Controller from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to present a new viewcontroller from a class outside of that viewcontroller.

It looks like this:

`AppDelegate.m` -> inside has this code:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Now, inside of that method is an object which utilises another class: `[actionSheet launchActionSheetNav];` this simply makes an actionsheet appear with different options.

Now, inside of `ActionSheets.m` is some code, involving a segue as follows:

```
handler:^(AHKActionSheet *as){

    ViewControllerYoutube *vc = [[ViewControllerYoutube alloc]init];
    [vc presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

All I want to do, is launch a new view controller from inside of there, however doing `[self.navigationController` brings an error that `ActionSheets.m` does not contain such method/property.

How can I present a viewcontroller from outside the original classes?

So the hierarchy is as follows:

Viewing Storyboard > Listening on `AppDelegate.m` > Inside that, a class method is called which takes you to `ActionSheets.m` -> and from there I need to display the new viewcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
ViewControllerYoutube *vc = [[ViewControllerYoutube alloc]init];
```

Creates a new instance of `ViewControllerYoutube`.  This ViewController doesn't exist anywhere else but that line, so when you follow it with this:

```
ViewControllerYoutube *vc = [[ViewControllerYoutube alloc]init];
[vc presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You're trying to present on a view controller that hasn't yet been presented.

If you want to present from an outside class, you need some way to keep a reference to the view controller you want to present, perhaps in your `ActionSheet.h`

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) ViewControllerYoutube *myViewControllerYoutube;
```

Then assign it when you create your action sheet (assuming you create it in ViewControllerYoutube)

```
ActionSheet * myActionSheet = [[ActionSheet alloc]init];
myActionSheet.myViewControllerYoutube = self;
```

Then instead of this:

```
ViewControllerYoutube *vc = [[ViewControllerYoutube alloc]init];
[vc presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Call this:

```
[_myViewControllerYoutube presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

#### UPDATE

Based on our chat, here's how I think we can solve it.

1. In `ActionSheet.h`:

   ```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) UIViewController *presentingViewController;
   ```
2. In 'ActionSheet.m'

   ```
   ViewControllerYoutube *vc = [[ViewControllerYoutube alloc]init];
   [_presentingViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```
3. In your AppDelegate:

   ```
   ActionSheet * actionSheet = [[ActionSheet alloc]init];
   UITabBarController * tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
   actionSheet.presentingViewController = tabController.selectedViewController;
   ```

Comment: how come your code has pretty colors, when i wrote exactly the same thing, and mine doesnt have any colors ?

Comment: @LenaBru - You have to use indentation. Wrapping code in these: ` is more for single line stuff.  Otherwise, add 4 spaces to your code.  Click edit on my answer and you can see the formatting how I did it.

Comment: @Logan Hey, thanks both for the comments. So, in `ActionSheets.h` I have put the property and then in the `.m` I have put this `ActionSheets * myActionSheet = [[ActionSheets alloc]init];
                                myActionSheet.myViewControllerYoutube = self;
                                ViewControllerYoutube *vc = [[ViewControllerYoutube alloc]init];
                                [_myViewControllerYoutube presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];` it doesnt crash anymore which is good, but doesnt work

Comment: make the property strong, not weak, it is probably nil, this is why it doesnt work

Comment: Jack4, you've extended the problem, but you're doing essentially the same thing.  You need to somehow pass the instance of `ViewControllerYoutube` to the class you want to call it from.

Comment: @LenaBru - No, that property SHOULD be weak.  That is not the problem. You don't want to add an unnecessary retain.

Comment: @Logan okay thanks, in the `.h` file I have `#import "ViewControllerYoutube.h"` which is allowing me access to the class - what is it I need to pass to the class im calling it from sorry?

Comment: Jack4, if you want to present on a specific view controller, you need a reference to that specific controller somewhere.  When you are creating a new object the way you are here, it's just that a NEW object.  It is not the same as the controller that is currently presented.  You need to maintain a reference to that SPECIFIC iteration.

Comment: @Logan just looking back, im calling it from `AppDelegate` so, based on this - when I do `actionSheet.myViewControllerYoutube = self;` before calling the class, im not passing the right thing for `self` - should this go one step before the `AppDelegate`

Comment: I put that step if you're calling from within ViewControllerYoutube.  Do you have a reference inside of AppDelegate to the specific iteration of ViewControllerYoutube you are presenting?  If so, it should be: `actionSheet.myViewControllerYoutube = thatReference;`

Comment: Imagine you just bought a new car.  You fill it with stuff, you paint it red, and you drive it to your friends house.  Then, later you want to use your car so you go to the dealership and buy an identical new car.  You get inside, but none of your stuff is there?  It's not the same car, you need directions to your original car which is parked at your friends house.  You need something that "points" to your original car's location . . . say, a pointer, because that SPECIFIC car is the one you're looking for!

Comment: @Logan I dont no; From the storyboard there is a `UITabBar` when the 4th tab is clicked it launches the action sheet which has multiple options on (which is called from the appdelegate so its already one step away from the storyboard). All I need it to do is click one of those and the relevant view controller pops up. Im so sorry for the stupid questions!! Its taking a while to sink in

Comment: So when a tab is clicked in the tab controller, it launches an actionsheet from the appdelegate?  Why not just launch it from the tabBarController?  Then push your new controller that way?

Comment: @Logan the error i get is "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'ViewControllerYoutube' *' from 'AppDelegate *'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52633/discussion-between-logan-and-jack4)

Answer (score 0):

you need to do 
    `[currentViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`

do you have any reference to "`correntViewController`" from this block? from this class? 
if not, do this

add a property
     `@property(nonatomic,strong) UIViewController *currentViewController`

in the given class

then in your `init` method, or in the usual `setCurrentViewController:`

pass the reference to the controller, 
and change you`[vc presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`
to
     `[self.currentViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];`